# Function to create new column with substring based on regex condition of another string column - python

Tags: python, regex, function

I have a string column and would like to create a function to extract parts of the string based on some conditions of the original string column

```
EMAIL               NUM_ID    
pat.l@abc.com       a9927345A
ginny.k@abc.com     B2722144X 
sandeep.a@abc.com   A2822876H 
khimmy.t@abc.com    b6722111A
rita.r@aba.com      X8923314X
```

Would like to create NEW_NUM_ID based on the first letter of NUM_ID.
If NUM_ID has "A" or "a" for the first alphabet, then the NEW_NUM_ID would pick the last 5 characters
If NUM_ID has "B" or "b" for the first alphabet, then the NEW_NUM_ID would be the original string
If NUM_ID has "X or "x" for the first alphabet, then the NEW_NUM_ID would be the original string

```
EMAIL               NUM_ID        NEW_NUM_ID
pat.l@abc.com       a9927345A     7345A 
ginny.k@abc.com     B2722144X     B2722144X
sandeep.a@abc.com   A2822876H     2876H
khimmy.t@abc.com    b6722111A     B6722111A
rita.r@aba.com      X8923314X     X8923314X
```

I have created the following code but can't seem to get it.

```
#Function to create the NEW_NUM_ID

def create_new_id(number_id):
    match = re.findall(r'^[a-zA-Z].*', number_id)
    if match[0] == 'A':
        return number_id[-5:]
    elif match[0] == 'B':
        return number_id
    elif match[0] == 'X':
        return number_id
    else:
        return 'NA'

df['NEW_NUM_ID'] = df['NUM_ID'].apply(create_new_id)
```

Appreciate any form of help I can get, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `str.replace` like

```py
df["NEW_NUM_ID"] = df["NUM_ID"].str.replace(r'(?i)^a.*(\S{5})\s*$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nQEnMK/1).

If there can be leading whitespace, use a `(?i)^\s*a.*(\S{5})\s*$` as regex. *Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive search and replace is enabled
- `^` - start of string
- `a` - an `a` or `A`
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(\S{5})` - Group 1: five non-whitespace chars
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

The replacement is the backreference to Group 1 value.

Answer (score 1):

Using `np.where` we can try:

```py
df["NEW_NUM_ID"] = np.where(df["NUM_ID"].str.contains(r'^[bBxX]'),
                            df["NUM_ID"],                           # original
                            df["NUM_ID"].str.extract(r'(.{5})$'))   # last 5
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works too

```
def create_iden_no(id_number):
    match = re.search(r'^(\w){1}', id_number)
    if match.group(1) == 'A':
        return id_number[-5:]
    elif match.group(1) == 'B':
        return id_number
    elif match.group(1) == 'X':
        return id_number
    else:
        return 'NA'

df['NEW_NUM_ID'] = df['NUM_ID'].apply(create_iden_no)
```